# File upload ['ERROR']= 2

Tags: php

I keep getting the file upload error 2, I know this means the file is bigger than the MAX_FILE_SIZE I set in the HTML form, but it is not. It is only 32kb when I set the MAX_FILE_SIZE value="100000". Why would I get this error? I already checked the upload file size and post upload settings in my php.ini and that is not the problem either.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_img.php">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"/>
<input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
<input type="file" name="picture" value="picture"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how is was solved, I think the updated html file wasn't actually getting saved

Comment: I'm also facing this error and I've noticed it's because the maximum file size specified in "value" should be a power of 2. In particular, I was setting value="500000" and I've turned it to value="524288"

Answer (score 22):

Remove this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000"/>
```

And in input "picture" set empty value:

```
<input type="file" name="picture" value=""/>
```

Comment: empty value string worked for me! thanks

Comment: I still use MAX_FILE_SIZE, but the value should be calculated by multiplying the desired maximum KB size * 1024.  So, for a maximum allowable upload size of 300K, the value would be 307200.