# $_FILES['file'] does not work for a simple procedure

Tags: php, file-upload

Unable to upload an image

- The problem is that the image does not get `set` as `$_FILES['file'].
- The code is very simple but still cannot get the obvious outcome.

> Have marked the unexpected trouble with 3* i.e. '***'

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance, your suggestions and comments are much appreciated.

Happy Coding!

<--- NOTE: HTML form below PHP --->

```
<?php
//CHECK: Submit
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo 'form submitted <br />';
    //CHECK: File by POST

    if(isset($_POST['file']))
    {
         echo $_POST['file'] . '<br />';
         unset($_POST['file']);
    }
    //CHECK: File if 'isset' $_FILES        
    if(isset($_FILES['file']))
    {
        print_r($_FILES['file']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo '$_FILES not set!';
    }
 }


?>

<!-- HTML FORM -->
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5M">
      Image: <input type="file" name="file" size="50" id="file" />
      <br /><br />
      <input style="margin-left:15%;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What output your are getting with this code?

Comment: Ouput:
form submitted
Array ( [name] => imagename.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 2 [size] => 0 )

Comment: isset($_POST['file']) why you are watching file in $_POST

Comment: Temp file upload path in php.ini is working?

Comment: I got form submitted 
Array ( [name] => a0960_002416 (1).jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => F:\xampp\tmp\php23C.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 0 )  May be the problem is related to your server

Comment: Looks like you may not have your [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) set correctly

Comment: Please use the below answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779221/file-upload-error-2

Comment: @Nes Thanx _error 2_ issue solved.

Comment: Cool enjoy the development

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
different value in name attribute
 Image: <input type="file" name="fileupload" size="50" id="file" />

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$name=$_FILES['fileupload']['name'];
$name=$_FILES['fileupload']['tmp-name'];
$name=$_FILES['fileupload']['size'];
}
?>
```

Comment: `file` is a legitimate name

Comment: Thanks! This does set $_FILES to the POST image but I do get an _error - 2_. Any ideas?

Comment: @Phil
True but when I changed the name to _fileupload_ it worked!
Then I changed it back to _file_ and it did not!
Some trick huh?!
Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your form action you missed `echo :-

```
  <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
         ^
```

As your comment, your are getting error 2 that means:-

> [UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

```
Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was 
specified in the HTML form.
```

Please refer this solution as well [File upload ['ERROR']= 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779221/file-upload-error-2)

Comment: I have that corrected in my actual code sorry for the mistake in here.

Answer (score 0):

Following correction are needed.

1 - Add an `echo` in `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` as `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

2 - Why your are finding `file` in `$_POST`, need a check to it

```
if(isset($_POST['file'])){
    echo $_POST['file'] . '<br />';
    unset($_POST['file']);
}
```

3 - You have commented your out put is from line `print_r($_FILES['file']);`

```
Array ( 
   [name] => imagename.jpg 
   [type] => [tmp_name] => 
   [error] => 2 
   [size] => 0 
)
```

tmp_name not getting blank that means your file is not creating its temporary file to upload. 
So, check temp upload file path in `php.ini` make sure it is working